# Serializing ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xml-serialization, observablecollection

I want to save an ObservableCollection that contains "Number" elements to the IsolatedStorage on the phone. I'm calling the SaveHistory() and LoadHistory() methods of my FileAcces class in App.xaml.cs whenever the app closes, activates, launches etc. I have a global variable defined in App.xaml.cs called *list* (ObservableCollection)

When debugging I'm recieving the error **InvalidOperationException was unhandled** (*There is an error in XML document (3, 4).*) on the line that says

`App.list = (ObservableCollection<Number>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);` (in LoadHistory())

```
public class FileAccess
{
    public static void SaveHistory()
    {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.CreateFile("History.xml"))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Number>));
                    serializer.Serialize(stream, App.list);
                }
            }
    }

    public static void LoadHistory()
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            //Make the file if it doesn't exist.
            if (!store.FileExists("History.xml"))
            {
                IsolatedStorageFileStream file = store.CreateFile("History.xml");
                //Dispose of the stream automatically created when creating the file. 
                file.Close();
                file.Dispose();
            }
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.OpenFile("History.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {
                //If the file isnt empty, then deserialize the xml into Settings objects and load them into the database.
                if (stream.Length > 0)
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Number>));
                    App.list = (ObservableCollection<Number>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                }
                else
                {
                    //If the file is empty, create a new ObservableCollection of Settings class type.
                    App.list = new ObservableCollection<Number>();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The contents of the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfNumber xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Number>
        <numbers>23</numbers>
    </Number>
    <Number>
        <numbers>50</numbers>
    </Number>
    <Number>
        <numbers>14</numbers>
    </Number>
    <Number>
        <numbers>76</numbers>
    </Number>
    <Number>
        <numbers>21</numbers>
    </Number>
</ArrayOfNumber>
```

According to [robtiffany](http://robtiffany.com/tag/observablecollection), in the article posted on the 5:th of November, serializing an observablecollection this way should work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the keyword is `There is an error in XML document (3, 4)`

Comment: Yeah, most likely :) So assuming there's nothing wrong with the code I've posted here, the problem must lie in my "Number" class? Does the Number objects have to be formatted in some sort of special way for the serializing of the list to work properly?

Comment: Post the content of your XML file

Comment: Hmm, where can i find the XML file? (I'm developing for Windows Phone)

Comment: get the xml file from isolated storage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I've added the xml file to the original question